# Fetch child products in grouped products woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to fetch child product ids of a parent grouped product, how to do that,
earlier woocommerce saves the child array in `wp_option` table as key to be `_transient_wc_product_children_ids_8` but the recent update has changed the way it saves to the database, plz help me, how can I fetch child products from parent product in grouped products.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `get_children()` method in the `WC_Product_Grouped` class.

```
$product_id = 8; // ID of parent product
$product    = get_product( $product_id );
$children   = $product->get_children();
```

It should return an array of product IDs.

**UPDATED for WooCommerce 2.5+**
Replaces `get_product()` with `wc_get_product()`

```
$product_id = 8; // ID of parent product
$product    = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$children   = $product->get_children();
```

Comment: `get_product` is deprecated; use `wc_get_product` instead

Answer (score 4):

On Woocommerce version 2.5.0 get_product is already deprecated.

Use [wc_get_product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product.html) instead

```
$product_id = 8;
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);
$product->get_children();
```

Comment: The link is 404.